How to Prevent iCloud Synchronization of SecureStorage in iOS for .NET MAUI?
I'm developing a cross-platform app using .NET MAUI, and I'm using SecureStorage to store sensitive data on iOS. However, I've read that by default, the data stored in the iOS keychain might be synchronized to iCloud, depending on the keychain's accessibility settings.
For security reasons, I want to ensure that this data stays only on the device and is not synchronized to iCloud or any other devices. Is there a way to configure SecureStorage in .NET MAUI to prevent iCloud synchronization on iOS?

When you interact with the keychain directly you can specify whether the keychain item is restricted to the local device. You may need to find another package that provides this access to keychain rather than using securestorage

For example this package allows you to specify whether the keychain item is synchronised

From the docs:

KeyChain data is synchronized with iCloud, and uninstalling the
application may not remove the secure values from user devices.

Also, the SecureStorage haven't implemented the kSecAttrSynchronizable capability natively as Paul as mentioned above. So you may use local .NET MAUI local databases to store sensitive data as an alternative choice.

Expecting the user to turn off iCloud Keychain because of one app's requirements is unrealistic.

I agree with @Paulw11. An alternative would be to use a local SQLite database package or another package that provides similar functionality to SecureStorage. It's surprising that this option isn't provided natively. What if I need to store a token without propagating it across all my devices?

The capability is provided natively- See my comment on your question.  It seems that the .Net Secure Storage does not expose that capability.

@Paulw11 Yes, thanks for the comments, I've updated that in my answer. :)
